# curl: (35) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified) Centos 7

Tags: curl, centos, nss

i am trying to establish a connection to the server using server signed certificate but i keep getting this error whereas both the CA and certificate are ok. Any help is highly appreciated. thanks

- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- skipping SSL peer certificate verification
- NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
- NSS error -12227 (SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT)
- SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.
- Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Comment: NSS is "Network Security Service" library. Mozilla uses it in lieu of OpenSSL.

Comment: Please post the URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, will run that command and give you feedback as soon as i get to office but on the other hand i verified the _signed certificate and the CA_ with openssl, all are ok. But the signed certificate is placed in the right store because when i curl the machine i use it gives me the certificate details problem is connecting to the server of the service provider and the other hand the the **URL**  is accessed via a private network its not public otherwise i would share it.

Comment: *"... on the other hand i verified the signed certificate and the CA with openssl..."* - OpenSSL 1.0.2 and lower do ***not*** perform hostname verification. *"... on the other hand the the URL is accessed via a private network its not public otherwise i would share it..."* - In that case Stack Overflow probably cannot help you. Perhaps you should talk to your network administrator.

Comment: ''_ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.10:443 -tls1 -servername 10.10.0.18:8070 | openssl x509 -text -noout_"
After running that command, this is the output i got

**140376943970208:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:598:
unable to load certificate
140445733816224:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE**
However when i send curl to same IP is see certificate details

Answer (score 0):

You have SSLVerifyClient="require" on your server. Maybe that helps someone.